# Creating a list of lists from round robin not using a recipe

Tags: python, list

I am new to python and trying to learn how to round robin of a list into a list of lists. I saw posts with answers pointing to a standard round robin recipe, but I don't understand some of the concepts in it and would prefer a simpler solution.

I want to achieve something like this using a function, but I haven't been able to come close:

```
MYLIST = ['apples', 'oranges', 'bananas', 'grapes', 'strawberries', 'pears']
>>>myfunc(MYLIST)
[['apples', 'grapes'], ['oranges', 'strawberries'], ['bananas', 'pears']]
```

I'm very confused after attempting to solve this problem using a combination of for loops, while loops and if statements. Nothing I did worked.

I don't have any code that works or comes close to working. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: for better answers add your code, it doesn't matter if it doesn't work!  
this way we can see where the problem is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**: This behavior is implemented in `more_itertools.distribute` [see documentation for details](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.distribute).  Simply `pip install more-itertools` and code the following:

```
import more_itertools

list_ = ['apples', 'oranges', 'bananas', 'grapes', 'strawberries', 'pears']
[list(c) for c in list(more_itertools.distribute(3, list_))] 
# [['apples', 'grapes'], ['oranges', 'strawberries'], ['bananas', 'pears']]
```

**Explanation**: The latter redistributes an iterable across `n` containers.

Note, this is not what the [`roundrobin`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) recipe does, which yields interleaved elements from `n` iterables, e.g. `roundrobin('ABC', 'D', 'EF') --> A D E B F C`.  This creates a single stream of elements that are not divided among separate containers, as you require.

Comment: What happens if there are more than 6 values or if have arbitrary number of values in main list?

Comment: See the link to the documentation.  In certain cases, empty lists are returned if the iterables are exhausted.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code I don't know much about round robin algorithm but,

```
l = ['apples', 'oranges', 'bananas', 'grapes', 'strawberries', 'pears']

half = len(l) / 2

l1 = l[:half]
l2 = l[half:]

l3 = []

for i in range(half):
    l3 += [l1[i],l2[i]],

print l3
```

Answer (score 0):

@Abhishek gurjar your code is giving a traceback with a TypeError. I think it is because of true division which outputs in float. It works if the expression len(l)/2 is inside an int() function. :)

```
l = ['apples', 'oranges', 'bananas', 'grapes', 'strawberries', 'pears']

half = int(len(l) / 2)
l1 = l[:half]
l2 = l[half:]
l3 = []
for i in range(half):
    l3 += [l1[i],l2[i]],
print l3
```

Answer (score 0):

since  you're new to python and you said that **"Nothing I did worked."** I guess you might not know that you can't pass some parameters to a function and make global effects inside the function.

here's a sample of what I'm saying

```
>>> def f(a):  
       a = [0,1,2,3]

>>> t = [0,0,0,0]
>>> f(t)
>>> t
[0,0,0,0]
```

how ever working with items of a list is ok

```
>>> def f(a):
        a[0] = 0
        a[1] = 1
        a[2] = 2
        a[3] = 3
>>> t = [0,0,0,0]
>>> f(t)
>>> t
[0,1,2,3]
```

also another solution is to return the result

```
>>> def f(a):  
       a = [0,1,2,3]
       return a

>>> t = [0,0,0,0]
>>> t = f(t)
>>> t
[0,1,2,3]
```